# SQL Server Express problem with accessing MS Access database over ODBC on network share via LinkedServer

Tags: sql-server, odbc, linked-server

if this question is answered somewhere I would like to apologize for that.

Let me explain my problem. Currently, we are in transition from MS Access database to SQL Server but
in meantime, we still need to use the old MS Access database and we need to update some Access tables
with data provided on the SQL server.
The Access database is located on the server (Windows Server 2016 without using Domain) in a separate directory( E:\LegacyDb )  then SQL Server and to access this data we are using Linked Server via ODBC connection using Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC drivers (yes I know we could use Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider but we had some problems with it). For the ODBC connection, we followed instructions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15.

When we first tried:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MYODBC, 'SELECT qty from stock')
```

it worked perfectly but when we tried to use an update:

```
UPDATE OPENQUERY(MYODBC,'SELECT qty FROM stock where id = 1') SET qty = 2
```

we got an error

```
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "myodbc" returned message "
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Cannot update. Database or object is read-only.".
Msg 7343, Level 16, State 2, Line 183
```

With some help on SQL forum from ErlandSommarskog answer, I googled a bit about folder permissions with SQL SERVER and find this post by Pinal Dave

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/06/24/how-to-find-service-account-for-sql-server-and-sql-server-agent-interview-question-of-the-week-179/

with that, I found exactly the name of the service account and then by following instructions from this post also by Pinal Dave

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/08/25/sql-server-fix-create-file-encountered-operating-system-error-5-access-is-denied/

a gave permission to that `E:\LegacyDb` folder and voila update worked.

This is perfect now, but now there is a second problem.

Unfortunately, we also have the MS Access database situated on a different PC in the network (we can't move it), folder location `\\SALES\LegacyDb` mapped to `Y:\`, but when we try to do the same thing there, we get a permission error, as the SQL server can't get to it. [odbc](/questions/tagged/odbc) is created normally as for local database on the server, but during Linked Server creation inside [ssms](/questions/tagged/ssms), we get an error that test connection is failed.

Any suggestion on how we can handle this situation, maybe what we want to do can be done in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

am not able to answer the question as asked.  but as another approach: if the task is need to update some Access tables with data provided on the SQL server - - and it is a split file multi user application where there is a Front End file... then
the front end can link to both back ends: Access & SQL Server.
so run the data transfer actions from the front end file i.e. query the sqlServer and trigger an append/update to the Access tables...

Comment: Hi, thanks, we are currently using this approach, but we want to schedule a job on SQL server to handle all the logic in the evening when the front end is not running,

Comment: am an Access developer - so I would set up a new specialty front end that simply is 1 form; use the Timer Event to fire the queries at whatever time is appropriate.  For a pure SQL Server solution hopefully someone will contribute a suggestion.